# How to use generic controllers and repository in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, templating

i'm doing a backend using spring-boot and hibernate, i created a generic controller to provide crud funcitonality automatically in all entities ( for example findAll, findbyId) and relative generic repository. Now al is ok, for better handling the relations lazy/eager loading i'm using @EntityGraphs and @NamedEntityGraphs to customize the loading of relations when a findById of an entity is called, to do this i have to put @entitGraph annotation in the findById definition of the entityRepository interface.
now all works fine if i call the findById from the specific entity controller instance, instead if i call the findbyid specified in the basecontroller (to be generic and not have to replace the method in all controllers) the entitygraphs does not work. Please help

```
public class BlocchettarioController extends 
BaseController<Blocchettario,BlocchettarioRepository> {

@Autowired
BlocchettarioRepository repo;


//  SHOW
  @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ResponseEntity<Blocchettario> show(@PathVariable(value = "id") 
Long id) {
      return repo.findById(id).map(record -> 
ResponseEntity.ok().body(record))
          .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
  }
}


public class BaseController<T extends BaseModel> {

    @Autowired
    private BaseRepository<T> repo;


    SHOW
    /*@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ResponseEntity<T> show(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {
         return repo.findById(id).map(record -> 
 ResponseEntity.ok().body(record))
                 .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }*/
}

//BaseRepository
public interface BaseRepository<T extends BaseModel> extends 
JpaRepository<T, Serializable>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> { 

}

//BlocchettarioRepository
@Repository
 public interface BlocchettarioRepository extends 
 BaseRepository<Blocchettario> {

     @EntityGraph( value = "blocchettario.showAll", type = 
 EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    Optional<Blocchettario> findById(Long id);
}

//Blocchettario.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "dp_blocchettario")
@NamedEntityGraphs({
        @NamedEntityGraph(name="blocchettario.showAll", attributeNodes =
            @NamedAttributeNode(value= "listaVerbali"  )) 
})
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "id")
public class Blocchettario extends BaseModel {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="blocchettario",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     private Set<Verbale> listaVerbali;


     public Set<Verbale> getListaVerbali() {
        return listaVerbali;
     }

    public void setListaVerbali(Set<Verbale> listaVerbali) {
         this.listaVerbali = listaVerbali;
    }


 }
```

In this way it works fine, instead if i comment the show method in BlocchettarioController and uncomment the show method in basecontroller it does not work anymore and doesn't load the listaVerbali relation.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `private BaseRepository<T> repo` in `BaseController` is intentional ? Shouldn't be `BlocchettarioRepository` ?

Comment: BaseRepository should be a generic repository, in basecontroller i want to provide generic crud for other controllers that extends basecontroller, so the basecontroller should not define a specific repository, but a generic repository. What i want is to retrieve the correct specific repository  when a specific contrller is called, using a generic definition, otherwise i should specify the crud mapping in every specific controller for every entitis

Comment: no one has any advice?